# Python streamlit code to display SubTables inside a column of a table

Tags: python, streamlit

Python streamlit code to display SubTables inside a column of a table.
For example, Under HColum2 and Address row we have a sub table with dynamically populated location information. Since it is dynamically populated, sub table will grow based on number of rows. Can any one help in this regard

`HColumn1   HColumn2 Name      Sunil Address   Column1  Column2  Country     India   State       Bangalore Age       35`

I am able to create a dataframe with simple table but not table inside a table

Answer (score 0):

i dont know exactly what you want but here is the code what i think you are looking for

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd

# Sample data
data = {
    'HColumn1': ['Name', 'Address', 'Age'],
    'HColumn2': ['', '', ''],
    'Sunil': ['', 'Column1', '35'],
    'Address': ['', 'Column2', ''],
    'Country': ['', 'India', ''],
    'State': ['', 'Bangalore', '']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Display the outer table
outer_table = st.table(df[['HColumn1', 'HColumn2', 'Sunil']])

# Add a sub-table inside a column
with outer_table.beta_container():
    st.write(" ", " ", df[['Country', 'State']])

# You can add more sub-tables or customize the appearance as needed
```

we create a DataFrame with the sample data, and the outer table is created using st.table() with selected columns. The sub-table is then added inside a column of the outer table using with

outer_table.beta_container():